# how to give the administrator privileges in Windows to my Java program?

Tags: java, file, makefile

I am developing a swing application and I need to create a file using FileWriter if the product activation is successful. but my problem is that windows does not allow my program to create files in the partition where Windows is installed. What should I do to allow my program to create files using FileWriter?   My program should be able to create a file without any confirmation from Windows...

Thank you

Comment: if u writing it directly on C:\(windows root dir) than its not good idea i suggest make tmp dir and than create file and check file.canwrite(). also make sure its absolute path.

Comment: You will need to run your program as some user who DOES have permission to write to whatever directory that is.